# Getting template dependent template type in C++

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, c++98

Well, I'm writing code in C++98 and trying to make use of metaprogramming.

I have written this kind of 'binder':

```
template<
    template<
        template<typename TArg1_1> class TArg1, 
        template<typename TArg2_1> class TArg2, 
        template<typename TArg3_1> class TArg3, 
        typename TArg4> class TFunction,
    template<typename TArg1_1> class TArg1,
    template<typename TArg2_1> class TArg2,
    template<typename TArg3_1> class TArg3>
struct MetaBinder_4_3_templates_1_1_1_0 {
    template <typename TArg4>
    struct type : public TFunction<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4> {};
};
```

What am I trying to do next is to 'bind' the arguments to it with the following code:

```
template<
    template <typename TType> class TApplier,
    typename TInitialType>
struct PreserveQualifiers : public PreserveQualifier<
    TypeClearVolatile, 
    TypeSetVolatile, 
    typename template <typename> MetaBinder_4_3_templates_1_1_1_0 <
        PreserveQualifier,
        TypeClearConst,
        TypeSetConst,
        TApplier>::type,
    TInitialType>
{};
```

`PreserveQualifier` is declared as follows:

```
template<
    template <typename TType> class TClearer,
    template <typename TType> class TSetter,
    template <typename TType> class TApplier,
    typename TInitialType>
struct PreserveQualifier;
```

But the code above actually gives me this error (GCC 4.7, my splitting into lines):

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 4)
error: provided for '
    template<
        template<class TType> class TClearer, 
        template<class TType> class TSetter, 
        template<class TType> class TApplier, 
        class TInitialType
    > struct PreserveQualifier'
```

I assume the problem is in `typename template <typename> MetaBinder_4_3_templates_1_1_1_0 <...>::type` construction syntax. And the actual question is: how should I specify dependent template type in this case?

Comment: Looks to me like an overcomplicated way to achieve something, I suspect, relatively simple. What is your goal? I might be able to suggest a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
MetaBinder_4_3_templates_1_1_1_0 <...>::template type
```

See a simplified example: [LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10936a40b7ec7043)